# how to compare all the fields of two feature class with 0 in one file and null value in another file and change it to the same value as of first file

Tags: arcpy, cursor

need to search the inputpolygon and checkpolygon and update the value to check polygon

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Inputpolygon,['market', 'type', 'latitude','postalCode'])as Cursorop:
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(checkpolygon,['market', 'type', 'latitude','postalCode'])as cursork:
      for row in Cursorop:
            for row1 in cursork:
                print(row,row1)
                for i in row:
                    for j in row1:
                        
                    if (i== "0" and j==None):
                        j = '0'
                        print("updated.")
                    elif (i== " " and j==None):
                        j = ' '
                        cursork.updateRow(row1)
                        print("eupdated.")
                    else:
                        print("elupdated.")
```

Comment: The code you have presented will generate a syntax error on line 2. I doubt this would work because of the faulty looping, but nesting cursors is always a mistake. Instead cache the searched features once and loop through the update once. If you don't describe what your code actually does, it's likely to be closed.

Comment: You can have multiple statements in one WITH statement. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for. Also, please add additional explanation of what are you are trying to do. A nested for loop means each column in your search cursor is being compared to each column in the update cursor, which doesn't really make sense. Adding an example before and after table to your question would also be helpful.